# hide/show table cell <TD> contents when hovering the <TR>

Tags: html, css, hover, show-hide

I'm a beginner in web development, HTML and CSS, so maybe my question will be a little bit cheesy.

I have a table containing two columns. Only one of them is the title and the others contain links.

What I want is to do the following: when hovered, the table the links will appear; otherwise, the links will be hidden.

Also, I want to apply a transformation move to their appearance...

Yeah, I searched on Google and I found many tutorials, but I could not apply any of these on my table.

I think there are some issues with my table styling? Maybe it's different form another elements styling?

Here's what I did so far.

**HTML code:**

```
<div id='historypanel'>
    <span class="truetables">
        <TABLE border=0><TR valign="top" class="panelfather">
            <TR>
                <TD width="130" class="linkcell">
                    <a href="link/" class="panellink">this is link</a>
                </TD><span id="options">
                <TD width="480" class="editcell">
                    <a href="edit.php" class="edit">edit &nbsp;</a>
                    <a href="drop.php" class="remove">drop &nbsp;</a>
                    <a href="hide.php" class="hide">hide permanently &nbsp;</a>
                    <a href="olden.php" class="old">old &nbsp;</a>
                    <a href="analytics.php" class="view">view analytics</a>
                </TD>
            </TR>
        </TABLE>
    </span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#historypanel>.truetables>table {
    margin-bottom: 5;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

#historypanel>.truetables>table:hover {
    background: #18323c;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    box-shadow: 2px 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

#historypanel a:link,a:visited,a:active {
    color: #112229;text-decoration: normal;
}

.panellink:hover {color: #5f9998 !important;}

.edit:hover {color: #528da4 !important;}

.remove:hover {color: #fc4c6d !important;}

.hide:hover {color: #75b096 !important;}

.old:hover {color: #ab856e !important;}

.view:hover {color: #dadb82 !important;}

a:link {text-decoration: none !important;}

.panellink {font-size: 20;}

.edit,.remove,.hide,.old,.view {font-size: 14px;}

.editcell,.removecell,.hidecell,.oldcell,.viewcell{
    padding-top:10
}

.editcell{text-align:right;}
```

You can also see it here: http://tinkerbin.com/xdHoEXgW

Comment: Could you please give two visual examples with the following criteria: at least three rows, what you want it to look like before hovering on a row, and what you want it to look like after hovering on a row?

Comment: now it's just one row and two columns.. before the hovering i want the second column contents (the links) to be hidden.. after hovering i want the contents to be shown.. just like that

Answer (score 0):

Few observations 
a. Please do follow the HTML table structure properly. ie Table can have "TR", "TR" has "TD".  You cannot insert "span" in between. Although it wont throw any issue.. its just not good coding

b. For transformation, u might have to use javascript (preferably Jquery).

I have modified your html http://tinkerbin.com/9vkBMX8a

You need to add these lines

```
.editcell{text-align:right;display: none;}
#historypanel:hover .editcell{display: inline;}
```

Answer (score 0):

all CSS answer:

```
.hidden_rows {
     display:inline-block;
     background: #18323c;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
     box-shadow: 2px 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
     transition:all 1s ease-out;
     -o-transition:all 1s ease-out;
     -moz-transition:all 1s ease-out;
     -webkit-transition:all 1s ease-out;}

.hover_me:hover .hidden_rows {
      display:block;}`
```